# window.scrollTo not working on next js after install react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-datepicker, next-router

I tried scrolling to the top page when refreshing the page. It's working. fine.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    }, []);
```

Then, install react-datepicker for custom date picker. but window.scrollTo function not working. Any idea or solution for custom date picker and window.scrollTo function.

Any idea or any solution...

Comment: Can you provide more of your component, or better yet a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I call window.scrollTo function in _app.js and call react-datepicker in body.js. Want more clarification?

Comment: Please provide surrounding code in `_app.js`  `window.scrollTo` is a native browser function, it should not be normally impacted.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?